# How do I get parity outlier code to run correctly?

Tags: java

You are given an array (which will have a length of at least 3, but could be very large) containing integers. The array is either entirely comprised of odd integers or entirely comprised of even integers except for a single integer N. Write a method that takes the array as an argument and returns this "outlier" N.

My code is below but when I run it, it doesn't look like the code is registering the `even += integers[i]` or `odd += integers[i]` so it always spits out 0. What am I doing wrong?

```java
public class FindOutlier {

    static int find(int[] integers) {
        int countEvens = 0, countOdds = 0;
        int oddOutlier = 0, evenOutlier = 0;

        for (int i=0; i < integers.length - 1 ; i++) {
            if (Math.abs(integers[i]) % 2 == 0) {
                countEvens++;
                evenOutlier += integers[i];
            } else {
                countOdds++;
                oddOutlier += integers[i];
            }
        }

        if (countEvens == 1) 
            return evenOutlier;
        else
            return oddOutlier;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine. I put it into a new main method, because you didn't include this, and created an integers array, and it ran fine. In the future, please put in code that can run, including the main method and the includes.

Answer (score 0):

Ah crap, I got it. The first test case had the outlier as the last element in the array so the "integers.length - 1" made it spit out 0 since the code didn't see the last odd number. Silly mistake, I was working on it for so long and I was sure it was right.

Comment: The for loop condition should be integers.length without the -1,